# What is meant by "each and every"?

Tags: contract-law, legal-terms

In a contract, what is meant by "each and every"? Isn't this the same as just "each"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of a number of redundant conjunctions commonly used in legal language – see Tiersma 1998 *Legal Language*, in this instance reflecting Anglo-Saxon poetic alliteration.

It means "each", which means "every".

Comment: You don't say what it means.